# rm -r crashes windows on cygwin

Tags: windows, git, cygwin

I have `cygwin` installed on my Windows 7 machine as part of installing `git`.  Whenever I do `rm -r` inside `Git Bash`, the machine crashes.  What could be causing this?

Comment: Did you try rebooting?  [This is actually relevant.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18503369)

Comment: Well it crashes the OS each time it happens, so there is no choice but to boot.

Comment: Antivirus interfering or damaged disk structure

Comment: I forgot to mention that `rd /s/q` in Windows works fine